# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to add react to exist project with webpack.
After

```
npm i react --save
```

I've add

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

to webpack app.js that contains all imports

But when I run

```
npm run build
```

I've got an error

ERROR in ./Project.Web/webpack/app.js

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in 'C:\source\Project.Web\webpack'
 @ ./Project.Web/webpack/app.js 330:0-26
```

So I guess a reason could be in webpack config 
In project there is webpack.common.config.js. I'm new in webpack but I'm surprised that there are no any ref to node_modules. So how it should be?

```
var path = require("path");
var webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            React: path.resolve(__dirname, '../node_modules')
            jquery: path.resolve(__dirname, '../Project.Web/SharedComponents/Components/jquery/jquery-1.11.3'),
            d3: path.resolve(__dirname, "../Project.WebU/SharedComponents/Components/d3/d3.js"),
            d3Tip: path.resolve(__dirname, "../Project.Web/SharedComponents/Components/d3/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"),
            underscore: path.resolve(__dirname, "../Project.Web/SharedComponents/Components/underscore/underscore.js"),
            hb: path.resolve(__dirname, "../Project.Web/SharedComponents/Components/handlebars/handlebars-v4.0.11.js"),
        },
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, "../Project.Web"),
            path.resolve(__dirname, "../Project.Web/SharedComponents"),
            path.resolve(__dirname, "./")
        ],
        extensions: ['.js']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: require.resolve('../Project.Web/SharedComponents/Components/jquery/jquery-1.11.3'),
                use: [{
                        loader: 'expose-loader',
                        options: '$'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'expose-loader',
                        options: 'jQuery'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: require.resolve("../Project.Web/SharedComponents/Components/d3/d3.js"),
                use: [{
                    loader: 'expose-loader',
                    options: 'd3'
                }]
            }
        ]
    },


    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jquery: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.jquery": "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            "window.$": "jquery",
            "d3": "d3",
            "d3.tip": "d3Tip",
            "_": "underscore",
            "Handlebars": "hb",
            "PubSub": "PubSub",
            "bootbox": "bootbox",
            "Mprogress": "Mprogress",
            "zxcvbn": "zxcvbn",

        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: Where is the `import React from 'react'; ` locate ?

Comment: @TonyNgo there is a file /webpack/app.js where all imports

Answer (score 0):

You can use this webpack setup for react that there is in my github:
https://github.com/behnamshateri/webpack-setup-for-react